# Can we define an oriented angular distance or arc measure?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, definition, geometric-measure-theory

Distance is always nonnegative, but it is often helpful to define an [oriented distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function).  Similarly, oriented volume is helpful e.g. to understand determinants.  I'm working on geometric problems involving arcs of circles where an oriented angular distance (or arc measure) would be helpful, but am struggling to come up with a consistent definition.

So far, I have:

For a given circle, fix an arbitrary orientation around the circle.  For two points $a, b$ on the circle, define *oriented arc measure* $\overset{\huge \frown}{ab}$ such that $$\begin{align*}
\overset{\huge \frown}{aa} &= 0 \\
\overset{\huge \frown}{ac} &= \overset{\huge \frown}{ab} + \overset{\huge \frown}{bc} \text{ if } a,b \neq c\\
\overset{\huge \frown}{ab} &= \pi \text{ if } ab \text{ is a diameter}\\
\overset{\huge \frown}{ab} &= -\overset{\huge \frown}{ba} \text{ if } ab \text{ is not a diameter}\\
\overset{\huge \frown}{ab} & \text{ is invariant under rotation around the circle's center}.
\end{align*}$$

**Questions:**

1. Is this definition consistent and well-defined?  I tried to ensure it covered all special cases.
2. If not, can it be repaired?
3. Is there a similarly intended definition or measure in the literature?

Comment: I see a couple of things on the definition: the arclength of ac should be less or equal to, not equal to; ab is $\pi\cdot$radius if ab is a diameter, not just $\pi$; ab = -ba, I am not really sure what you want to express with this. If the sign - means moving in the opposite direction to the given orientation, that is true, but otherwise I don't see it.

Comment: @juanzaragoza I edited to clarify that I am referring to arc _measure_ (measured in radians), not a linear length.  $ab = -ba$ because this measure is _oriented_: e.g. if to go from $a$ to $b$ we need to sweep $\frac \pi 4$ radians, then to go from $b$ to $a$ we sweep in the other direction, so $-\frac \pi 4$. And I maintain that indeed $ac = ab + bc$ as long as $a,b,c$ are all different (this worked in every example I tried). Why do you disagree?

Comment: ac = ab + bc works if, following the orientation, you start in a, then b appears and later c. In such case, yes, ac = ab + cb, but your statement does not exclude the case were you have first a, then c, then b (a = (1,0), c = (0,1), b = (-1,0) and counter clockwise orientation works for what I am trying to express), in which case $\leq$ is required, isn't it? Regarding the ab = -ba, I think that you need to come up with something clearer: if a = (1,0), b = (0,1), and counter clockwise orientation, $ab = \pi/4$ but $ba = \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **directed angle**, which has properties similar to the above (e.g. $\angle AB = -\angle BA$).  The key is to take angles mod $\pi$ (some authors, when dealing with arcs and not angles, use mod $2 \pi$.)

See [Kedlaya's *Geometry Unbound*](https://kskedlaya.org/geometryunbound/gu-060118.pdf) for properties.